# Failed to load AutoStartRichPresence (BetterDiscord MacOs 10.14.6)

Tags: javascript, discord

To day i want to install AutoStartRichPresence but i get failure loading of javascript code and didn't find answer for this.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/zlib'
    at Object.T [as realpathSync] (<anonymous>:4:342022)
    at Function.getFilePath (<anonymous>:4:343292)
    at Function._load (<anonymous>:4:343387)
    at <anonymous>:4:346578
    at eval (betterdiscord://plugins/AutoStartRichPresence.plugin.js:104:18)
    at eval (betterdiscord://plugins/AutoStartRichPresence.plugin.js:2014:6)
    at eval (betterdiscord://plugins/AutoStartRichPresence.plugin.js:2273:5)
    at eval (betterdiscord://plugins/AutoStartRichPresence.plugin.js:3729:3)
    at Object.requireAddon (<anonymous>:4:37871)
    at Object.loadAddon (<anonymous>:4:8814)
    at Object.loadAddon (<anonymous>:4:35543)
    at Object.loadAllAddons (<anonymous>:4:11288)
    at Object.initialize (<anonymous>:4:5710)
    at Object.initialize (<anonymous>:4:34738)
    at Object.startup (<anonymous>:4:392305)
```

MacOs-10.14.6
arch-i386
BetterDiscord core-1.8.5

Answer (score 0):

This plugin broke over a year ago and was never updated by the developer. Unfortunately, fixing the plugin is not straightforward and it would be easier to just make a completely new one which some developers are actively working on.

If you want to get around this specific error and still attempt to use this plugin, you can bundle zlib (or similar from userland) and update the functions accordingly.